# Texture baking turns part of my object black

Tags: texture-baking

I'm trying to bake a texture of mine, but it keeps making the circular window fully black, I'm not sure if it is a problem with the mesh, any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know, 9 months late. I'm new to blender, but I figured this one out. If you have gloss in your material, you have to make a separate gloss map. The color is there. Save the diffuse map first, then make the glossy with a new texture map (save that), and finish by reloading the diffuse map. You now have 2 maps, plug them in where appropriate, and all should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. Texture baking shows all shadows from the point of view of the light(s) in the scene. Since some parts of your mesh would be in shadow, this is how the texture bakes.